# Create a class which inherits from an array of SKSpriteNode in Swift

Tags: swift, class, skspritenode

I'm trying to create a class in SpriteKit but I don't know if it's possible.

I know that :

```
class myClass: SKSpriteNode
{
    var myVar: Int = 0
    var mySecondVar: Int = 0
}
```

will create a class which inherits from the SKSpriteNode class.

Then, in order to create a 2 dimensionnal array from this class, I use this :

```
var array = [[myClass]]()
```

So I can add elements with

```
 var elements = [myClass]()

 elements.append(myClass(imageNamed: "image"))
 elements.append(myClass(imageNamed: "image"))

 array.append(elements)
```

So here, I can access myVar and mySecondVar using

```
 array[x][y].myVar
 array[x][y].mySecondVar
```

But what I want to do is that mySecondVar would be a variable from myClass, so here it's ok, but I want to access myVar using this sort of syntax :

```
 array[x].myVar
 array[x][y].mySecondVar
```

And I don't know how I could do this, I tried this :

```
 class myClass: [SKSpriteNode]
```

but it doesn't work. Could you try to help me ?
Thanks.

Comment: Why should you want to do that? Your desired use case seems to imply that `myVar` should be `static`, but also in that case I don't see why getting the array. Can you describe what `myVar` represents a bit better?

Comment: Oh sorry I just realized that I made a mistake in my post, I put myClass[x].myVar instead of array[x].myVar, you can check the new code below, do you understand it better ?

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice that! But no, doesn't help much. If you can describe _why_ `myVar` should be a property of the array instead of the instance would help. Otherwise maybe you should just create a wrapper class for `[SKSpriteNode]`

Comment: I want to create a game where I have many laser beams. Each laser beam is made of two SKSpriteNodes : the emitter and the reciever. I store those laser beams in my array. So I got a laserBeams[x][y] array, x represents the number of the laser beam and y is 0 or 1, represents the two SKSpritesNodes. I want to have a property on these SKSpriteNodes: mySecondVar (for example the temperature of the emitter or the reciever : laserBeams[x][y].temperature), and I also want to have a property for the laser beam itself, myVar (for example is the laser active ? laserBeams[x].isActive). Is it clearer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, I suggest you do it differently altogether. In this way we represent the problem in a more specific and easy-to-use way:

```
class LaserBeam {
    var emitter: SKSpriteNode
    var receiver: SKSpriteNode
    var isActive: Bool
}
class LaserNode: SKSpriteNode {
    var temperature: CGFloat
}

var array: [LaserBeam] = ...
```

Comment: Well, I really didn't thought about this option, I'll try it out but it seems way more easier, thanks. Edit: Did you mean `var emitter: LaserNode`, instead of `var emitter: SKSpriteNode` ?